# How to reduce a property within an array of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, reduce

I have an array of `products` which in turn have an array of `categories`. I want to extract distinct values of the `type` property on `category` object.
Both the Lodash and native versions below do the job.
I want to make a generic function which takes the path of property and return unique values.

Essentially I am looking at something terse like
`map(products, property("categories[].type")` but heres the longer version(s)

```
import { compact, flatten, map, property, uniq } from "lodash";

export const getAllTypes1 = (products) => {
  return uniq(
    compact(map(flatten(map(products, property("categories"))), "type"))
  );
};
export const getAllTypes2 = (products) => {
  const types = [];
  products.forEach((product) => {
    product.categories.forEach((category) => {
      if (!types.some((t) => t === category.type)) {
        types.push(category.type);
      }
    });
  });
  return types;
};
```

Example data

```
const product1 = {
  name: 'Wilson Orange',
  price: 72.50,
  categories: [{
    type: 'flash sale',
    discountable: false,
  },{
    type: 'tennis',
    discountable: true,
  }]
};
const product2 = {
  name: 'Babolat Green',
  price: 65.50,
  categories: [{
    type: 'tennis',
    discountable: true,
  }]
};
const products = [product1, product2];
```

Result

```
const result = getAllTypes2(products);
console.log(result); // ["flash sale", "tennis"]
```

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-microservice-3vlbcn)

Comment: "I want to make a generic function which takes the path of property and return unique values." Do you mean similar to how your code works with the 'type' property? So to get the same result as the current example you want to pass 'category.type`?

Comment: Check out lodash's `get`, which accepts a string "path" to the data. Plug that into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS function that takes the path without needing `[]` and automatically checks arrays wherever it finds one.

How it works is:

1. Create an empty `Set` to easily remove duplicates
2. Turn the path string to an array of properties -> `props`
3. Call a recursive function `recurse(currObj, props)` which:

   1. Checks if the `currObj` is an array, and if it is:
      a. Recurses again with the array values as `currObj`
      b. Use the same `props` since we didn't check an object in the path
   2. Check if we're at the last prop in the path, if yes
      a. Add the property's value in the current object to the set
   3. Otherwise. recurse with `currObj[currProp]`, and the remaining props
4. Convert the set to an array and return it.

```js
const product1 = {
  name: 'Wilson Orange',
  price: 72.5,
  categories: [
    {
      type: 'flash sale',
      discountable: false,
    },
    {
      type: 'tennis',
      discountable: true,
    },
  ],
};
const product2 = {
  name: 'Babolat Green',
  price: 65.5,
  categories: [
    {
      type: 'tennis',
      discountable: true,
    },
  ],
};
const products = [product1, product2];

function getProperties(array, path) {
  const props = path.split('.');
  const values = new Set();

  function recurse(currObj, props) {
    const currProp = props[0]
    const nextProps = props.slice(1);
    if (Array.isArray(currObj)) {
      for (let val of currObj) {
        recurse(val, props);
      }
      return
    }
    if (nextProps.length === 0) {
      values.add(currObj[currProp])
    } else {
      recurse(currObj[currProp], nextProps)
    } 
  }
  recurse(array, props);
  return [...values];
}

console.log(getProperties(products,'categories.type'))
console.log(getProperties(products,'price'))
console.log(getProperties(products,'name'))
```

Comment: This code is [vulnerable](https://medium.com/@zub3r.infosec/exploiting-prototype-pollutions-220f188438b2), example `getProperties({}, '__proto__')`

Comment: Definitely. Its functional contract relies on a valid intentional input.

Comment: But not to be a man without solutions, if OP wants to safegaurd against that, then they can add a line in `recurse()` with `if (currProp === '__proto__') return`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a property path string, but it's pretty terse and expressive:

```js
const pipe = (...fs) => fs.reduceRight(
  (next, f) => x => f(x, next), x => x,
);
const getAllTypes = pipe(
  (x, next) => [...new Set(x.flatMap(next))],
  (x, next) => x.categories.map(next),
  (x) => x.type,
);
// equivalent to
// const getAllTypes =
//   x => [...new Set(x.flatMap(y => y.categories.map(z => z.type)))];

const products = [{
  name: 'Wilson Orange',
  price: 72.50,
  categories: [{
    type: 'flash sale',
    discountable: false,
  }, {
    type: 'tennis',
    discountable: true,
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Babolat Green',
  price: 65.50,
  categories: [{
    type: 'tennis',
    discountable: true,
  }]
}];

console.log(getAllTypes(products));
```

The parameter `x => x` allows `pipe` to be called without any arguments and return the identity function. It also allows the last function argument of `pipe` to accept a `next` parameter for consistency, i.e. `(x, next) => next(x.type)` would have been equivalent to `(x) => x.type`.

Reference:

- [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)